# Let $f(x)$ denotes the number of zeros in $x!$. If $f(m)-f(n)=3$, then value of $\frac{(m-n)_{max}-(m-n)_{min}}{2}$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recurrence-relations

> > Let $f(x)$ denotes the number of zeros in $x!$.
> > If $f(m)-f(n)=3$, then value of $$\frac{(m-n)_{max}-(m-n)_{min}}{2}$$ is?

**Solution Provided in book:**

Given $f(m)-f(n)=3$

If $m=125$,  $n=124$ $\implies$ $(m-n)_{min}=1$

$m=24$, $n=5$ $\implies$ $(m-n)_{max}=19$

So Final Answer is $\dfrac{19-1}{2}=9$.

**My doubt** How did author of book came at such random value of $m,n$?

Comment: Is $f'(x)$ the derivative of $f$? Or just a random function? Was there some context before this? I'm very confused here.

Comment: I wrote the exact question as provided in book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the question in your book has a typing error ,that is in place of zeros in f′(x),it meant zeros in x!.(To be very honest,I had a gut feeling and when I cross-checked it with the solution provided it matched!!).